# pre login initialization =29237; handshake=26244

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security, connectivity, kerberos

Connecting to one of my servers ([no mirror or availability group running](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/163197/22336)), from a local machine and I get this error message below related to [handshake](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/40355/22336) when the firewall is up.

when the firewall is down it connects straight away.

the question I would like to address is:

is it always these `number below (29237 and 26244)` that sql server uses for connection?

I am aware of the [port numbers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107766/22336) on single and multiple instances.

This server by the way is not a named instances.

`initialization =29237; handshake=26244`

or does it change? if so then - based on what?

we have [had issues with one domain controller](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/116694/22336) but I have ruled that out.

[image]

I haven't even touched [authentication schemas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242688/22336) and [Kerberos](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/162087/22336)

Comment: not a 100% sure but as it said "The duration spent..." I would assume that those number are the time spend (probably in milisecond) to do the initialization and the handshake (an not port number)... Does it take about 1 min to get that error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the comment by [Dominique Boucher](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/105483/dominique-boucher) those number seems to be indication of time, as per the picture below they vary.

> "The duration spent..." I would assume that those number are the time
>   spend (probably in milisecond) to do the initialization and the
>   handshake (an not port number)...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, SQL uses port 1433 and 1434 (if you are using named instance or the DAC connection).

You can validate which port is used using SQL Server Configuration Manager

[image]